# Swift Optional binding, why the need for a local var?

Tags: swift, optional-binding

I'm reading Apple's developer documentation on [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333)

Why can't I use:

> if someOptional? {
>
> > statements
>
> }

Instead of

> if let constantName = someOptional {
>
> > statements
>
> }

Why when there is no need for a local variable or constant?

Comment: you use optional binding when you want value from the optional...not just check if the  optional value contains value or nil

Comment: you can always do `if someOptional != nil {` or if you don't need the unwrapped value you can also do `if let _ = someOptional {`

Answer (score 5):

> Why can't I use: if someOptional? {...}

Because the `?` suffix on an optional variable is reserved for [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), which allows you to access a property or call a method on a given optional variable. For example:

```
// returns an optional version of a given property
let aProperty = anOptional?.someProperty

// calls the method if aProperty contains a value – otherwise doesn't
aProperty?.doSomething()
```

If you just want to check whether an optional contains a value, but don't care about that underlying value, you can simply compare it with `nil`. For example:

```
if anOptional != nil {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If you're interested, I co-wrote [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) that lists (almost) all the ways of safely working with optionals – although the Apple Swift docs are hard to beat!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that someOptional is an Optional, whereas constantName is a Type.

An Optional is not simply the state of a variable, it's an entirely different type. If you were to set `var someOptional: String?` to `var someOptional: String`, you're not unwrapping someOptional, you're actually changing the type of someOptional.

It's functionally the same as changing `var someOptional: String` to `var someOptional: Int`